# Gradle Tomcat plugin - static resources hot deploy

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gradle, static-files, hotdeploy

I've read that [Gradle Tomcat Plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) supports hot code deployment.

What about **static resources** such as CSS, JS and HTML files? Is it possible to have the plugin to "monitor" the static files for changes and re-deploy them? At the moment I'm forced to restart tomcat through `Ctrl + C` + `gradle tomcatRunWar` to see the changes in the browser.

If hot deployment for static resources is not available/possible, where is the plugin keeping a copy of them? As a workaround I'm thinking of using rsync.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally recommended to use the [Gretty](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty) rather than Gradle's built-in Jetty or Tomcat plugins. Gretty has support for hot-deployment of web resources as well as serving static resources strait from your workspace.